# How to accurately measure Python socket connect

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, wireshark

I'm trying to accurately measure the time taken for a TCP 3-way handshake to complete using the socket module.

I'm using time.perf_counter() to provide a timestamp:

```
try:
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    sock.connect( (address, int(port)) )
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    sock.close()   
    conn_time = "%8.5fms" % ( (t2-t1)*1000.0 )
```

which provides the required granularity, however a Wireshark capture shows the calculated time is much longer than the actual connection time.

I'm not sure if the issue is with the time module or at what point the code moves from sock.connect to t2, i.e. at what point does the socket module determine the connection to have been successful.

Any suggestions for more accurately measuring connection time appreciated.

Comment: What are you measuring exactly in Wireshark? And on which side? (Or somewhere in the middle?)  I would expect this code to measure the time it takes for the local system to send the `SYN` and receive the `SYN+ACK` in response, and (probably) to *enqueue* the subsequent `ACK`. Certainly I *wouldn't* expect the third part of the handshake to have actually been *received* by the far side before the time of your second call to `time.perf_counter`.